# Access: Query specific users not in a profile

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that displays user profile and users assigned.

Example

```
Profile    User
--------   -----
ProfileA   UserA
ProfileA   UserB
ProfileA   UserC
ProfileB   UserA
ProfileB   UserD
ProfileC   UserB
ProfileD   UserE
```

I am trying to create a query to verify that a group of specific users are not in the profile and display those profiles.

Example:
I want to display the profiles where **UserA** and **UserC** are not assigned to.

Output Example:

```
Profile
--------
ProfileC
ProfileD
```

I am trying to create this query in MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you have a table of profiles.  If so, use `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from profiles as p
where not exists (select 1
                  from user_profiles up
                  where up.profile = p.profile and up.user in ('UserA', 'UserC')
                 );
```

If you don't have a separate table -- which would seem odd to me -- you can do this with the profiles in your table.  But in this case, conditional aggregation is a simple method:

```
select profile
from user_profiles
group by profile
having sum(iif(user in ('UserA', 'UserC'), 1, 0)) = 0;
```